# Chrome Extension all_frames for http://*/* pattern

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome Extension's content script allows to specify if scripts should run in all pages. I have the following in the manifest, but when I try to send a message to the tab, it doesn't have the iframes context.

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "js": [
    "utils.js",
    "listener.js"
  ],
  "run_at": "document_start",
  "all_frames": true
},...]
```

Perhaps there are 2 instances of the content script that are loaded and only the top is reached via sendMessage (chrome.tabs.sendMessage)? I suspect the very broad matches might be causing a problem?

My extension permissions:

```
"permissions": [
"webNavigation",
"webRequest",
"webRequestBlocking",
"notifications",
"cookies",
"tabs",
"storage",
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*"]
```

Comment: oh good question, I was trying to do something very similar a while ago and gave up.  Be curious to see the answer to this one.

Comment: You might try creating a [long-lived message connection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) from the content scripts to the background script if they are in a frame. You would have to track the connections in the background and send messages to the specific frames you are interested in.

Comment: I do have a such long-lived message connection that among other things sends a message when the page is loaded. However I only see the message from the main frame in the tab. I have tried sending the onload message using `chrome.extension.sendRequest` but still only 1 gets fired.